# "Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment" in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I'm trying to add a SharePoint group to a specific list that exists on all the sites in a collection. I would think this would be easier but I'm having difficulties. Inheritance is already broken on the list.

Below is my code and then the error I'm getting.

```
$siteNumbers = "2210"
$listsOnSite = "QWERTY"

Foreach($wnl in $siteNumbers)
    {
    $rootWeb = (Get-SPWeb ("http://url/to/site/" + $wnl))


    Foreach($lst in $listsOnSite)


    {
    $list = $rootWeb.Lists[$lst]
    $group = $rootWeb.Groups["Global Read-Only QWERTY"]
    $role = $rootWeb.RoleDefinitions["Read"]

    $roleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
    $RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role)
    $rootWeb.RoleAssignments.Add($RoleAssignment)
    $list.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
    $list.Update()
    }
    $rootWeb.Update()
    }
```

> New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate
>   constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment. At line:9
>   char:33
>   +     $roleAssignment = New-Object <<<<  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment( $group)
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentExce    ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.C
>   ommands.NewObjectCommand
>
> Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "The permission level
>   specified i s already added to the collection." At line:10 char:47
>   +     $RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add <<<< ($role)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:12
>   char:30
>   +     $list.RoleAssignments.Add <<<< ($roleAssignment)
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeExcept    ion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:13
>   char:17
>   +     $list.Update <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Update:String) [], RuntimeExc    eption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: I was able to reproduce the "Constructor not found" exception by setting $group to null. Are you sure the "Global Read-Only QWERTY" group exists?

Comment: I'm positive. I ran a script to verify. 2210
contains the following groups
========================
Global Read-Only QWERTY
Main Members
Main Owners
Main Visitors

Comment: Check this  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147617/adding-read-only-permissions-to-a-list-for-a-sharepoint-group-using-powershell-c

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPPrincipal]$group)
```

Instead of

```
$roleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
```